# How can I change the option with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of the options. When I click on the button It will must to change the first option on the second from "level.value", but the first option changed also.

```
<div id="containerForLevel">
  <label for="levelImpotance">The Level of a importance: </label>
  <select id="levelImpotance">
    <option value="#36BBCE">normal</option>
    <option value="#FFD700">important</option>
    <option value="#D2006B">very_important</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="button"><input type='button' value='Click'></div>

$("#button").click(edit);
function edit() {
   var level = {value:"important"};
   $("#levelImpotance :selected").text(level.value);    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CrashReactor/9hn38u5f/

How can I change the option on the "level.value" When I click on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
var secondOptionValue = $("#levelImpotance option").eq(1).val();
$("#levelImpotance").val(secondOptionValue);
```